# Different way to specify matching new line in Python regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I find out there are different ways to match a new line in python regex. For example, all patterns used in the code below can match a new line

```
str = 'abc\n123'
pattern = '\n'   # print outputs new line 
pattern2 = '\\n' # print outputs \n
pattern3 = '\\\n' # print outputs \ and new line
pattern4 = r'\n'  # print outputs \n
s = re.search(pattern, str).group()
print ('a' + s + 'a')
```

I have 2 questions about this:

1. pattern is a new line, pattern2 and pattern4 is \n. Why python regex generates the same pattern for different string?
2. Not sure why pattern3 also generates the same pattern. When passed to re parser, pattern3 stands for \ + new line, why re parser translates that into just matching new line?

I am using Python 3

Comment: From your explanation, it definitely generates different pattern

Comment: but i get the same output for all of them. I just went back and double checked. I think they should generate different pattern but the result contradicts me

Comment: Actually I read that post, I think my main question is about parsing '\n', when regex parse it, does it treats it like a new line or just \n then parse it, what is the underlying mechanism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The combo `\n` indicates a 'newline character' in *both* Python itself *and* in `re` expressions as well (https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/strings.html).

In a regular Python string, `\n` gets translated to a newline. The newline *code* is then fed into the `re` parser as a literal character.

A *double* backslash in a Python string gets translated to a single one. Therefore, a string `"\\n"` gets stored internally as `"\n"`, and when sent to the `re` parser, *it* in turn recognizes this combo `\n` as indicating a newline code.

The `r` notation is a shortcut to prevent having to enter double double backslashes:

> backslashes are not handled in any special way in a string literal prefixed with `'r'` (https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

Comment: Thank you! But what about the third pattern '\\\n', how re parser parses it? it is one backslash + new line.

Comment: @user2628641: it is parsed exactly the same. The two backslashes are parsed as a single one, followed again by a regular newline combo `\n`.

Comment: So ‘\\\n’ = \ + a newline character, when re parser sees this, it will try to escape the newline character, but can’t, so it will just take the newline character as the pattern. I think that is what happened?

Comment: @user2628641: ah I see what you mean. Yes, the combination `\+(literal newline)` does mean nothing. It depends on the specific `re` engine what happens next; most indeed then ignore the backslash, and store only the following character in the to-search expression.